# How to use Intel MKL instead of libopenblas in Julia

Tags: julia, intel-mkl, openblas

I would like to know if there is a way i can use Intel MKL library instead of OpenBlas. I have installed MKL. Below is the version info

```
Julia Version 0.6.0
Commit 903644385b (2017-06-19 13:05 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: macOS (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Haswell)
  LAPACK: libopenblas64_
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.9.1 (ORCJIT, haswell)
```

Kindly let me know if this can be done

Answer (score 3):

This is the procedure I have used to install **Julia** (0.6.0) with **Intel MKL** (compiling from source) in **macOS Sierra**. Remember to uninstall previous versions of Julia first.

- Install [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/).
- Launch a Terminal and update the command line tools:

  ```
  $ xcode-select --install
  ```
- Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).
- Use Homebrew to install **gfortran**:

  ```
  $ brew install gfortran
  ```
- Take advantage of Homebrew and install also **wget**:

  ```
  $ brew install wget
  ```
- Go to the **Intel Performance Libraries** [webpage](https://software.intel.com/en-us/performance-libraries), register yourself and download these free libraries for OS X and install them (as with a regular DMG package):

  1. Intel Threading Building Blocks (TBB)
  2. Intel Math Kernel Library (MKL)
- Download the Julia source (Tarball with dependencies):

  ```
  $ wget https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/releases/download/v0.6.0/julia-0.6.0-full.tar.gz
  ```
- Uncompress the file and move the folder to your `$HOME` directory.
- Launch a Terminal and change to the Julia source directory:

  ```
  $ cd ~/julia-0.6.0
  ```
- With your preferred tool, edit the file `Make.inc` and enable the use of Intel MKL and Intel MKL FFT. Save and close the file. Use the picture as a guide:

[image: Enabling Intel MKL in Make.inc]

- Set up the Intel MKL environment, for Intel64 architecture with 8 bytes integer support (ILP64):

  ```
  $ source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64 ilp64
  ```
- Compile Julia:

  ```
  $ make
  ```
- If there is a problem compiling Julia, create a symbolic link in the Julia's lib folder to the Intel MKL library and run make again:

  ```
  $ ln -s /opt/intel/mkl/lib/libmkl_rt.dylib usr/lib/libmkl_rt.dylib
  $ make
  ```
- I did not try to run `make install` because I do not have Administrator privileges in my Mac, but you are free to do it. Anyway, you can run Julia from this folder:

  ```
  $ ./julia
  ```
- Next time you open a Terminal probably your Intel MKL variables would have gone. Just add these lines to your `~/.bash_profile`:

  ```
  # Intel MKL
  source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64 ilp64
  ```

Comment: Do note that the intel links need to be opened with a chrome browser, or you'll be linked to a broken form page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible but much easier to do if you are happy to re-install a clean version of julia.

You will need to edit the `Make.user` file as described here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia#intel-compilers-and-math-kernel-library-mkl

Comment: thank you very much for the response. I have installed Julia using macOS dmg package hence I am unable find Make.inc file. Kindly let me know if there any other way to Setup MKL.

Comment: Sorry the only way I know is if you install it from source. It's not too difficult if you follow the guidelines on the above link.